# Find columns present in one table and not in another.Please read description

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two versions of database V5 and V9.
V9 being the latest version.
I have to find the columns in similar table name that are present in table of V9 and not in V5.
example, table name : ashish_table in V9 has 5 columns A,B,C,D and E.
                      same table ashish_table in V5 has 3 columns A,B and C.

So there are two columns D and E present in  table ashish_table of V9 and not in ashish_table of V5.

I have made connections between these two databases. I also searched and found below script which compares tables based on "data_type, data_length, data_scale, data_precision";but it matches only  the columns with same name.
eg. it will match column A,B and C based on data_type, data_length, data_scale, data_precision; if suppose datatype of column A has been changed from char to varchar and other two columns details are same then it will return only column A.
It does not give D and E which is not existing in ashish_table  of V5.

```
set verify  off 
set heading off
column data_type format a20

accept table1 prompt 'Table 1: '
accept table2 prompt 'Table 2: '

prompt
prompt The table &table1 and &table2 have columns with the same name but differ:
prompt -------------------------------------------------------------------------

select 
       column_name,data_type, data_length, data_scale, data_precision
from  
       user_tab_columns
where 
       table_name = upper('&table1')
minus
select 
       column_name,data_type, data_length, data_scale, data_precision
from 
       user_tab_columns
where 
       table_name = upper('&table2');
```

Thanks for reading the big question.
Is there any script which compares two tables and gives the missing columns.

Comment: Use a product such as Red Gate sql compare

Comment: downloading any software is disabled by admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to find if there are any extra columns:

```
select c2.table_name,c2.COLUMN_NAME
from all_tab_cols c2
where table_name='&table1'
and c2.COLUMN_NAME not in (select column_name 
    from all_tab_cols 
    where table_name='&table2');
```

This is untested but can do this:

```
select 
       column_name,data_type, data_length, data_scale, data_precision
from  
       user_tab_columns
where 
       table_name = upper('&table1')
minus
select 
       column_name,data_type, data_length, data_scale, data_precision
from 
       user_tab_columns
where 
       table_name = upper('&table2');
union
select c2.COLUMN_NAME, c2.data_type, c2.data_length, c2.data_scale, c2.data_precision
from all_tab_cols c2
where table_name='&table1'
and c2.COLUMN_NAME not in (select column_name 
    from all_tab_cols 
    where table_name='&table2');
```

Comment: I check the 2nd script.It is working fine when two tables are compared in same database.
But when I am running the same script for different databases it is giving all the output of second table.I also used distinct because output given was duplicate.
Also I have made link to both databases successfully.
What could be the reason for such a behaviour?